# How do I view the my network map in windows 8.1?

Tags: networking, windows-8

I've recently discovered an extremely useful feature called Link Layer Topology Discovery in Windows 7 - I click on "See Full Map" in the network and sharing center. 
[image]

And it outputs this lovely, very useful network diagram

[image]

However, in windows 8 and later, See Full Map is missing. However, the underlying protocols for LLTD are still available, and my system is detected.

[image]

How would I access the full network map from windows 8.1 or later versions of windows?

I'd also want to use LLTD, not a 'naive' IP address scan as was suggested in one of the answers. Unlike a IP address scan, it works on layer 2, and detects things like which access point a system is connected to in my multi-ap setup, and which systems are connected to the same switch. I'm looking at LLDP as an alternative, but thats a whole different kettle of fish

Comment: hmmm, if we knew which files were used in W7 to do this. I still use hyperterminal, copied the files off an xp machine and works well.
Does anybody know which files would have to be copied for the network view utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... this may not be possible natively. But, you can always use an external tool. One such tool is [LanScan](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/lanscan/23324308-b07d-471b-b6d5-24ac9a0bb595). From this post's recommendation: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/compensate-for-the-missing-network-map-feature-in-windows-8/

Comment: Thats no different from doing an IP address scan, and for my purposes falls well short of what I need. I have one main router (which does wireless), and two APs. Systems switching between APs maintain the same IP address and MAC address. LLTD detects which AP a system is on, which systems are on the same dumb switches, and even to an extent, my homeplug AV network. A lot of that gear dosen't even have IP addresses

Comment: The listing in Windows explorer appears to still be layer 2.

Comment: While its not the answer I want "Its not possible natively" and "Its been removed" does seem to be correct. I've selected this as the correct answer, though, I'd warn that if someone does find a way to make this work, I'll both switch the accepted answer, and gleefully award a bounty.

Comment: FYI, as of 2017-11-08, the app isn't available via the store; "Lanscan is currently not available"

Comment: @PeterFnet, which os are you on?

Comment: @GauravJoseph , Windows 10 Enterprise 1709. Tested again today, it's not there. I also pulled down the source code for it; it was built for pre-Windows 10 (Windows 8/Windows 8.1)