# How to find IP of Wireless AP (NOT the router, just the AP!)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, traceroute

My Wireless AP is a Tp Link TL-WR740N. It's continuing to broadcast its SSID and I can connect to it and use the WiFi and indeed connect to the internet (via the router) using it. However I need to login to the GUI to check the radio is on 2.4ghz as well as 5ghz. I'm also having some problems which means I want to reset to factory settings. I cannot for the life of me find the AP's IP. I've tried Angry IP Scanner, "arp -a" and a tool for the iPhone (when connected to the AP) called iNetTools which allowed me to do a trace route. I tried to do a trace route to the router which I thought would show the IP of the AP. It did not. It said 5 relative hops but then only showed the router IP.

I've tried a hard physical reset by holding in the reset button for 30s (and over) but it doesn't seem to react. I'm half wondering if DD-WRT is installed on the AP but even then it ought to react to the 30s reset?!

HELP!

Cheers

Comment: Get Advanced IP Scanner (Famatech - Free) and try that. This finds my Wireless AP, shows the make and IP address in the line finding it.

Comment: This is all going to be a lot simpler to search over ethernet from a computer. What platform do you run?

Comment: Since an AP is mostly transparent, an IP scanner is the only way you could find it. Keep in mind that it could be on a different subnet.

Comment: ugh, windows 7 had an *excellent* tool for this using LLDP that newer versions dropped for some inscrutable reason

Comment: It's quite possible that the AP isn't on the same subnet as your network, especially if it's been running for a while and you've had a new router in the meantime. Have you done a "_30-30-30_" reset? (press reset, wait 30s, power off, wait 30s, power on, wait 30s, release reset). The default IP is `192.168.0.1` or `192.168.1.1`, so you may need to manually configure the computer's network interface. `traceroute` and `arp` won't likely help here.

Comment: It's also quite possible that the AP has been told not to respond to such queries over wifi - it's a simple intrusion prevention measure. Running `arp -a` over wired ethernet is the logical first step.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have Windows 7 PCs on the same LAN. I also have access to a Mac and Debian.

Comment: @Tetsujin Run Win7 and Debian. I AM currently ethernet connected to the same LAN as the AP. I will have another look :-) Thank you

Comment: OK, then run `arp -a` from anything you have access to that's only ethernet-connected. Nothing in my building will respond to 'intrusion/diagnostic/admin' requests over wifi, you have to go wired before they will answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks - but I've tried this as I said in my OP (but possibly didn't make clear that I was ethernet connected at the time) and it lists a lot of MACs but not the MAC of the wireless AP. It's so weird!

Comment: AH, OK - sorry, I hadn't realised that from your OP. I know a couple of Mac tools that *might* find it, but all are paid, so see what people can come up with for Win/nix that might be free.

Answer (score 0):

[Nirsoft's WifiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) might help you with that.

Make sure the AP is not getting interferences from other APs/channels.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - don't think the AP is being interfered with due to being on an overlapping channel - it's working just fine - the problem is I can't find its IP to connect to the web GUI. The router (192.168.2.1) and the wireless IP are TWO separate bits of kit. Thanks

Comment: In that case you should **cable** connect it to a workstation and set it up properly with a static IP.

Comment: The static IP thing is tricky because my NETGEAR router has a bug whereby it won't display the GUI either. God, just writing this shows me how frustrating these problems are. And then when they multiply, the frustration is far more than the sum of their parts. Because the problem with the NETGEAR router is now making the TP-Link AP even harder to find than it already is...

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows 7 (for some reason it was the only version of windows that had proper support for it), it has a LLTD tool built in, that you can access from "full map" in network settings.

I have a [question asking for it on newer versions](https://superuser.com/questions/707102/how-do-i-view-the-my-network-map-in-windows-8-1) that shows the UI. It'll even show a network device that's got [no IP (intentionally or otherwise)](https://superuser.com/questions/806656/finding-the-ip-address-of-a-walled-in-router)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this from the computer connected to the AP.

Answer (score -1):

The router's IP IS the one of the gateway if you are within the LAN side of it.
So route -n (or ipconfig /all on Win) shows the IP as the gateway IP.

[Maybe your problem is more that you do not get an HTTP connection to the management GUI. This could have different reasons, and needs its own analysis.]

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The router and the wireless AP are two separate bits of hardware