# How to find device that belongs to a certain IP in a workgroup?

Tags: networking, dns

My Router in an external warehouse tells me this:

> Warning: Following static Hosts may generate addressing conflicts in
> LAN: 00:10:18:--:--:-- [192.168.150.102] Resolution Note: Please
> configure the IP address of the static hosts outside the dynamic LAN
> address range.

My Problem is, I have no idea what device this is. Is it a printer? is it a computer? is it a label printer? if so, which computer/which printer? is it a completely different device?

It has no web interface so it should not be a printer because all printers we use have a web interface. The network is a workgroup with a router and some network switches and clients so I have no DNS Server that I could query.

Can I somehow get any information, like a hostname, or a model or anything that could help me identify this device?

Some things that I have tried:

Ping:

```
C:\Users\997>ping 192.168.150.102

Ping is executed for 192.168.150.102 with 32 bytes of data:
Response from 192.168.150.102: Bytes=32 Time=1ms TTL=128
Response from 192.168.150.102: Bytes=32 Time=1ms TTL=128
```

nslookup:

```
PS C:\Users\997> nslookup 192.168.150.102
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::125a:f7ff:fe62:89c2

*** 192.168.150.102 was not found by UnKnown: Non-existent domain.
```

Get Host By Address:

```
PS C:\Users\997> [net.dns]::GetHostByAddress("192.168.150.102")
Exception when calling "GetHostByAddress" with 1 argument(s): "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found".
no data of the requested type was found".
In line:1 character:1
+ [net.dns]::GetHostByAddress("192.168.150.102")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException
```

When I just try to `Stop-Computer`:

```
PS C:\Users\997> stop-computer 192.168.150.102
stop-computer : The RPC server is not available.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ stop-computer 192.168.150.102
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (192.168.150.102:String) [Stop-Computer], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StopComputerException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopComputerCommand
```

Network card manufacturer:

```
MAC-Segment:    00:10:18:00:00:00 - 00:10:18:FF:FF:FF (MA-L)
Hersteller: Broadcom
Adresse:    16215 ALTON PARKWAY
IRVINE CA 92619-7013
US
```

nmap:

- `nmap -sL 192.168.150.0/24` doesn't show a hostname for this IP
- `nmap -O 192.168.150.102` can't read OS information and can't read/connect to any port

Comment: Run `nmap` against that IP? That or basically DDOS it and see who starts swearing.

Comment: I remember Windows 7 had a nice network mapping tool that used LLTD but it appears removed in later versions. Perhaps that or a new alternative might help pinpoint the device physically? https://superuser.com/questions/707102/how-do-i-view-the-my-network-map-in-windows-8-1 or https://www.solarwinds.com/network-topology-mapper (second one is a paid product but looks like it has a trial)

Comment: Most (free) network scanners can pick up hostnames etc., other than that you will only get information about the network adapter. Checking for open ports might also give you some hints.

Comment: @Mokubai hmm nmap -sL doesn't show a hostname for that specific IP (but those for others in DHCP Range). nmap -O can't find a OS. I'll look for some network mapping tools

Comment: Apparently zenmap (https://nmap.org/zenmap/) is a GUI for nmap that looks like it has at least some kind of topology view. https://nmap.org/book/zenmap-topology.html

Answer (score 0):

To find hostnames for the IPs in a subnet without having to
send a packet to the individual hosts themselves, use
nmap with the -sL flag.

This flag tells nmap to do a simple DNS query for the specified IP.

The following example comes from the article
[10 nmap Commands Every Sysadmin Should Know](https://bencane.com/2013/02/25/10-nmap-commands-every-sysadmin-should-know/):

```
 $ nmap -sL 192.168.0.0/24
 Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-02-24 09:59 MST
 Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.0
 Nmap scan report for router.local (192.168.0.1)
 Nmap scan report for fakehost.local (192.168.0.2)
 Nmap scan report for another.fakehost.local (192.168.0.3)
```

The article describes additional nmap parameters for getting information
such as the Operating System of a host. Some require root permissions.

Comment: This command was mentioned as being ineffective in the comments.

Comment: @Mokubai: I didn't see it. This is probably caused by the local network setup. I'll leave this answer here anyway for future readers.